# RaycastHit2D doesn't collide with objects that has Collider2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my first game on unity, which is based on grabbing fish, which is based on Raycast and Colliders. I copied some code and modified it a bit, but it seems that when I launch the Ray, it doesn't collide with the fish 
 (`GameObject`) that has a `Collider2D`, and it gives me `NULL` on the `Hit.Collider` value. I've got a `GameObject` which contains the script, and from it the Ray launch and fishes that has colliders.
By the way, I drew a line to prove that the ray reaches the `GameObject` (Fish) and it does, but not collide.
Here's my code, then there's images:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class grapplinghook : MonoBehaviour {

    DistanceJoint2D joint;
    Vector3 TargetPos;

    public float maxdistance;
    public LayerMask mask;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        joint = GetComponent<DistanceJoint2D>();
        joint.enabled = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) ) {
            TargetPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            TargetPos.z = 0;
            Vector2 TargetPos2D = new Vector2(TargetPos.x, TargetPos.y); 
            Vector2 CurrentPos2D = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);

            RaycastHit2D Hit = Physics2D.Raycast(CurrentPos2D, TargetPos2D, maxdistance);
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, TargetPos2D, Color.black);
            if(Hit != null)
                Debug.Log("trueeeeeeeeeee");
                Debug.Log(Hit.collider);
                Debug.Log(Input.mousePosition);

            if(Hit.collider){
                joint.enabled = true;
                Debug.Log("true" + Hit.collider.gameObject.name);
                joint.connectedBody = Hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                joint.distance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, Hit.point);
            }
        }
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)){
            joint.enabled = false;
        }

    }
}
```

I have found that the difference between the coordinates of WorldPoint and Screen has something to do with my problem through a video on youtube at minute 16: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eF8F5NHZoHQ&t=1246s

The thing is that the coordinates when I use `ScreenToWorldPoint()` are bigger than `Input.mousePosition`.

Answer (score 0):

Physics2D.Raycast takes two Vector2's as it's first two parameters: origin and direction.

Origin is the point where the Ray will start, and direction is the direction in which the Ray will go.

You are using it as if it were going from point A to point B. If you want a Ray that goes from A to B, your origin should be point A, but the direction should be B - A (as that is the way to calculate the direction from A to B).